# How to create a search folder based on email attachment file names?

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I'd like to have a smart folder containing all the emails with attachments which have certain words in their file name.

I can create a regular search query like this just fine by going to "More" > "Attachment contains" in the ribbon and then entering the string I'm looking for in the new field appearing below the search box. But I can't find a way to directly save this search in a search folder, nor have I been able to manually recreate this in a new search folder.

Please tell me there's a way to achieve this!

(I'm using Outlook 2016 on Windows.)

Answer (score 1):

Based on my test on the Outlook client, there seems to be no such a way to create a search folder for mail containing attachments with specific name becase. And I‘m afraid that only the search folder containing attachments could be created(Right click Search folder>New search folder>Mail with attachments>OK).
[image]

In addition, I have done research and found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12283189/how-to-move-mail-to-a-folder-based-on-attachment-filename) which mentioned that vba could be used to move mail to a folder based on attachment filename. Please refer to it if you need and hope it will help you.

Comment: I am writing to see if there is any progress on the issue. If you have any questions or need further help on this, feel free to post back.